# .where on 2 date fields. If the first field is nil search the second field

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im trying to find `PickUp` that are in the future based on 2 different fields.

If `latest_eta` is `nil` then search by `scheduled_at`. I have to search by 2 fields because `latest_eta` is most reliable but sometimes its not available for a `pickup`.

My current scope is.

```
  scope :by_future_pickup_eta, -> {
    joins(transit: :pickup)
      .where(TripStop.latest_eta > Time.current)
      .where(TripStop.scheduled_at > Time.current)
  }
```

It doesn't seem to work.

For clarification this spec should pass

```
before do
  example[2].transit.pickup.update(latest_eta: 1.minute.from_now)
  example[0].transit.pickup.update(latest_eta: nil, scheduled_at: 15.minutes.from_now)
  example[1].transit.pickup.update(latest_eta: nil, scheduled_at: 30.minutes.from_now)
  example[3].transit.pickup.update(latest_eta: 45.minutes.from_now)
end

it "scope .by_futurepick_up_eta" do
  expect(Example.by_future_pickup_eta.pluck(:id)).to match [
    example[2].id,
    example[0].id,
    example[1].id
    example[3].id
  ]
end
```

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: This works.

```
  scope :by_future_pickup_eta, -> {
    joins(transit: :pickup)
      .where('coalesce(trip_stops.latest_eta, trip_stops.scheduled_at) > ?', Time.current)
      .order('coalesce(trip_stops.latest_eta, trip_stops.scheduled_at) desc')
  }
```